# facebook audience network testing on test flight No Fill

Tags: objective-c, facebook-sdk-4.x, facebook-audience-network

testing our app when running on xcode is good and we can see ads even without test mode (device hash), so we can see live ads. Everything is setup fine, but when we test the app on test flight, It's always returning a log of "No Fill".. :S,

We have logged in the facebook native app, Limit ads tracking is disabled..

What do you think is still the problem? Is it required from facebook that the app is live on apple store?

Thank you very much!..

Comment: What is the error code you're getting?

Comment: I'm not sure if this situation is applicable to yours, but I did find someone with a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34110193/3487310

Comment: If you guys found any solution regarding this:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055218/how-to-resolve-error-1001-no-fill-using-facebook-audience-network-in-android? if yes then post answer on this question please.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in TestFlight.

By design, TestFlight generates a new and different IDFA in each run. Those IDFAs are different from your device IDFA which is used by Facebook native app. When your app sent ad requests with those new IDFAs to Audience Network, the server cannot matching the IDFA to get the proper ads and returns 'NO FILL' back. That is what exactly you have experienced.

Here is the link for detail:[iOS: TestFlight beta app get new advertising identifier in each run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26648840/ios-testflight-beta-app-get-new-advertising-identifier-in-each-run).

The solution is to get off TestFlight and run the app directly through the device, or continues to use TestFlight but with Facebook test ad only.