# How to make the Facebook ads live?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook-audience-network

I have added Facebook audience network in my iOS App for native ads integration. Everything is working fine but there are only testing ads.

I have added testDeviceKey for displaying ads if I try to remove this then no ads are displaying that is also making me confused. My code is -

```
@implementation AdFeedsView

FBNativeAd *nativeAd;
static NSString *adPlacementId = @"xxxxxxxxx";

- (void)showNativeAd:(UIViewController *)vc
{
   nativeAd = [[FBNativeAd alloc] initWithPlacementID:adPlacementId];
   nativeAd.delegate = self;

   NSLog(@"isTestMode1: %d",[FBAdSettings isTestMode]);
   NSString *testDeviceKey = [FBAdSettings testDeviceHash];
   if (testDeviceKey) {
     [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:testDeviceKey];
   }
  [nativeAd loadAd];
}
```

So I just want to ask that what changes should I need to do in my code so that we can see proper ads other than testing ads in my live app?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I find the solution. Actually I have added the code

```
NSString *testDeviceKey = [FBAdSettings testDeviceHash];
if (testDeviceKey) {
 [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:testDeviceKey];
}
```

that is making all the active devices as testing devices hence there are only testing ads. I have removed it in the live version and included the code

```
[FBAdSettings clearTestDevices];
```

We can also do

```
if ([FBAdSettings isTestMode]) {
    [FBAdSettings clearTestDevice:[FBAdSettings testDeviceHash]];
}
```

I have a wrong perception about ***testmode***. I think that it will be false when my app become live but actually it just tell that the device has been added as testdevice or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3**

This code will make sure that your test ads show on testflight or the simulator/device and also will make sure when you release to the app store that your ads will be shown as **LIVE** ads and the test devices will be cleared.

If you have your ads in many places you can put this code in the AppDelegate

```
import FBAudienceNetwork

private func facebookAdsControl() {
    #if RELEASE
         self.clearTestDevicesForFacebookAds()
    #else
         self.addTestDevicesForFacebookAds()
    #endif
}

///remove for live mode
private func addTestDevicesForFacebookAds(){
    let key = FBAdSettings.testDeviceHash()
    FBAdSettings.setLogLevel(FBAdLogLevel.Log)
    FBAdSettings.addTestDevice(key)
}

///add for live mode
private func clearTestDevicesForFacebookAds() {
    FBAdSettings.clearTestDevices()
}
```

call the: `facebookAdsControl()` in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

You can also call this code in the code where you have the ads but make sure you call it before `adView.load()`

In order to use the macro you have to add the flags to your Swift Flags in the Build Settings

I hope this helps someone as the Facebook Docs are not very clear as I have found out.

Comment: will this code work on adhoc build or not.? If we add this peace of code in the appdelegate.?

Comment: @MuhammadDanishQureshi to be honest I am not working on the project that I used the above code so not sure if it is at all relevant at this moment in time.